# New fancybox shifts to the right again

Tags: html, css, fancybox

I've downloaded the new fancybox pack 2.1.5. I've noticed that this version has an old bug! When fancybox pops up the background shifts to the right.

In Fancybox 2.1.4 you could fix that with

```
.fancybox-lock{
  overflow:visible !important;
  margin-right:0px !important;
}
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
  overflow-y: inherit!important;
}
```

This, however, doesn't work in this new version. I tried everything (ie changing class names etc) but with no luck.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: @Pete: I use FF newest version, but it happens in Chrome and IE too

Comment: @Pete: Me neither... Could this be a Bootstrap 3 issue?

Comment: make sure you download the latest master https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/archive/master.zip